# Float Output / Input questions in C

Tags: c, floating-point

I would like your help with understanding the following:

For the code:

```
int main() {
    int i=23;
    float f=7.5;

    printf("%f", i);
    return 1;
}
```

The output is `0.000000`, how come it is not `7.500000`?

For the code

```
int main() {
    int i=23;
    float f=7.5;

    printf("%d\n",f);
    printf("%f",i);
    return 1;
}
```

The output is `1455115000, 7.500000`. Why doesn't it make an error compilation? what is this number 1455115000? and why now 7.500000 is being printed?

Comment: General reference; This is covered by the `printf` documentation.

Answer (score 8):

Mismatched format/arguments in your `printf` calls causes undefined behaviour.  If you turn up your warnings level, your compiler will probably tell you that.  For example, `clang` gives this warning for your first program:

```
example.c:5:10: warning: conversion specifies type 'double' but the argument has
      type 'int' [-Wformat]
printf("%f", i);
        ~^   ~
        %d
```

and these ones for your second:

```
example.c:5:10: warning: conversion specifies type 'int' but the argument has
      type 'double' [-Wformat]
printf("%d\n",f);
        ~^    ~
        %f
example.c:6:10: warning: conversion specifies type 'double' but the argument has
      type 'int' [-Wformat]
printf("%f",i);
        ~^  ~
        %d
```

And that's with no special flags at all.  `gcc` warns by default on your programs, too.  Example 1:

```
example.c:5: warning: format ‘%f’ expects type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
```

Example 2:

```
example.c:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’
example.c:6: warning: format ‘%f’ expects type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
```

Both of those compilers also warn about your implicit declaration of `printf`, but I left those messages off, since they're not strictly related to your question.

Answer (score 1):

> The output is 0.000000, how come it is not 7.500000?

Because `%f` tells `printf` to expect a `float`, but `i` is not a `float`.  So you are invoking **undefined behaviour**.

> Why doesn't it make an error compilation?

In GCC (and probably other compilers), you'd get a warning message.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the first case you are trying to print the value of `i`, to get the
   value `7.5` you need to print `f`.
2. In the second case, the problem is a *mismatch* with the format
   specifiers and the arguments provided to `printf()`

More on 2.

To print a `float` value it needs to be paired with the `%f` format specifier. For `int`eger values this should be `%d`.  These are backwards which is why you are seeing the undefined behavior/output as a result of this mismatch.

If you compile your programs with the highest warning level, you might get a warning about these types of mismatches/errors.

***Aside***:

Generally a return value of `0` indicates a successful program termination. A *non-zero* value (like `1`) indicates a problem. Probably not relevant for your program, but something you might want to keep in mind.